# Getting null reference error in response.filter while implementing gzip in sitecore website

Tags: gzip

I am getting null value in response.filter.Below is my code. I am getting response but in response.filter value is null.I am implementing it sitecore website.

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.IO.Compression;

public class Compress:ActionFilterAttribute
    {

            public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)

     {       var _encodingsAccepted = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Accept-Encoding"];
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_encodingsAccepted)) return;

            _encodingsAccepted = _encodingsAccepted.ToLowerInvariant();
            var _response = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;

            if (_encodingsAccepted.Contains("deflate"))
            {
                _response.AppendHeader("Content-encoding", "deflate");
                _response.Filter = new DeflateStream(_response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
            }
            else if (_encodingsAccepted.Contains("gzip"))
            {
                _response.AppendHeader("Content-encoding", "gzip");
                _response.Filter = new GZipStream(_response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Question is "`response.filter (_response.Filter)` after setting value using " new `DeflateStream`" or "new `GZipStream`" still gives you Null?

please debug `DeflateStream` or `GZipStrem` for Errors.

Please check the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpresponse.filter?view=netframework-4.8

If My understanding of your question is not correct, please Elaborate on your question further.

Hope this helps.